# Detect Persian Duplicate Words by REGEX

Tags: php, regex, farsi

I want to detect duplicate persian words by regex. I have seen examples with english words, but they did not work with persian words.
Something like this : `\b(\w+)\b`, this works with english, but does not work with persian characters.

I want to detect `آران` in `آران وبيدگل آران و بيدگل`.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure `'/\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)/u'` does not work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I totally forgot to use the unicode flag. That's what OP should be after =)

Comment: @JvdV  `((?<=^|\p{Z})\p{L}+(?=$|\p{Z})).*\1` won't work because you are not matching diacritics with `\p{L}` and `(?<=^|\p{Z})` / `(?=$|\p{Z})` only matches whitespace boundaries.

Comment: Yes, so it is a duplicate of two other threads combined. The links are on top.

Comment: Should I delete my question ?

Comment: No, it is good, let's keep it.